# how do you zoom/resize an image after it is loaded?

Tags: html, image, imageview, carousel, zooming

**Background:**

I'm creating a image carousel that shows 50% scaled images, but when an image is clicked a pop-up viewer shows the actual-sized version of that image, provided the image isn't larger than the viewer.

When the image is smaller than the pop-up viewer, then it is displayed as it is actually sized.

When the image is larger than the pop-up viewer, then it is scaled to fit in the viewer, but not clipped.

The pop-up viewer limits the overall size of the image, so that controls positioned around the image aren't disturbed by the image when it is zoomed in or out, which is the next feature I want to add to the pop-up viewer.
Here is a small chunk of code, but the whole thing is in CodePen.

```
<style>
  /* These aren't the actual values, they are dynamically calculated to fit
     the browser's viewport to prevent the image area from growing so large
     that it doesn't fit completely on the screen when the original image is
     either initially too large or the <img> width value is set by the user
     that causes the image to grow too large that one or both of the parent
     div's scrollbars 'switch-on'. */
  div > img {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
  }
</style>
<div style="overflow: auto;">
  <img style="object-fit: contain; width: 100%;" src="">
</div>
```

**Goals:**

When zooming, either in or out, the the pop-up viewer's image area size doesn't change, instead the image inside of that area, grows or shrinks as the image is zoomed in or out.

**Partial Solution:**

Here is the code in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/howardb1/full/PoqPvda) for the carousel and the viewer.  The carousel works and clicking one of the images does show it in a pop-up viewer.

This version incorporates Stefan F. and LakshmiS solution on how to fit the images into the image area.

Another version supports zooming and scrolling when the image is larger than the viewer's image area, but, moving the image around in the image area using the horizontal and vertical scrollbars is kind of awkward.  Is there a way to click-drag the image around within the image area, as an alternate to the scrollbars?

Answer (score 0):

You can add "object-fit: contain" to the css of your image.

```
div#myModal > div.modal-content > div.mySlide > img {
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer. Yes object-fit:contain will suits for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this make the img element fit the full parent element's width and then make the image sized to fit in the img element, but maintain the aspect ratio of the image's actual height to width?  Is this fully supported in the current version of IE, Edge, and the modern browsers?

Comment: In short yes, object-fit: contain will fit the image in the parents container. It will not be distorted but rather cut if the parents container is very different. 
You can use it directly in the css for all the browsers except ie. https://caniuse.com/#search=object%20fit
But for ie there is a polyfill library if you really need to maintain it. https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

Comment: Thanks for the object-fit: contain solution and the information.  Do you have any information on how to zoom and scroll-around in the zoomed image?